# php date() isn't working when adding days and saving into DB

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I am trying to create a date and add 3 days to it, I am then saving it into a mysql db with the date field type.

Here is what I have.

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+3 days"));
```

Then I insert into the db. I end up getting 0000-00-00 instead of the date, but if I echo it out it looks correct.

However, if I use

```
date('Y-m-d')
```

then insert it into the db, it works fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

I found out doing more debugging that my value isn't being passed to my query, I didn't catch this before as I am using a built in CMS function and it wasn't thowing me an error.

Comment: This calls for basic debugging. What is the result of the `date()` operation? What is the result of the `strtotime()` operation?

Comment: What do you get for the output of `strtotime("+3 days")`?

Comment: [Works fine for me.](http://codepad.org/VJU0YThS) Could you show some context?

Comment: I get today using `strtotime()` and `date()`. I also get today + 3 days using `strtotime('+ 3 days')`.

`date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+3 days"))` Echoed gives me the same as strtotime('+ 3 days')`.

Comment: Could you post your query, please?

Comment: make sure you are placing it correctly in your query and not using the MySQL's date function.

Comment: The code you've posted in your question as well the question itself is unrelated to your problem. This really calls for basic debugging first. If you do not get any errors and you feel unsure you can do some things to improve your situation: 1.) Enable error reporting to the highest level for debugging/development purposes. 2.) Check return values from functions for error conditions and report these errors your own. 3.) Verify each parameter you use for functions if it contains a valid value and is needed after all and that no important parameter is missing.

Comment: @hakre, I'm using a CMS and I already have error bugging turned on to the highest settings.

I have found the problem and will try to work it out. It seems that my value isn't being passed to my query for some reason, thanks for your help everyone.

Answer (score 3):

Things to check:

1. output of `date('Y-m-d'` and `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+3 days'))` (echo them out).
2. show the query string you're inserting this value into, including the file version of the query before you execute it
3. Consider to switching over to using pure MySQL operations for this, .e.g.

   `INSERT INTO ... VALUES (now() + INTERVAL 3 DAY)`

instead, saving a few roundtrips from native->string->native->etc...